# Queries running very slow on first load on PostgreSQL

Tags: performance, postgresql, heroku, pg

We are using a PostgreSQL version 9.4 database on Amazon EC2. All of our queries run super slow on the first try, until it gets cached after that they are quite quick however it is not a conciliation  as it slows down the page load.

Here in one of the queries we use:

```
SELECT HE.fs_perm_sec_id,
   HE.TICKER_EXCHANGE,
   HE.proper_name,
   OP.shares_outstanding,

(SELECT factset_industry_desc
 FROM factset_industry_map AS fim
 WHERE fim.factset_industry_code = HES.industry_code) AS industry,

(SELECT SUM(POSITION) AS ST_HOLDINGS
 FROM OWN_STAKES_HOLDINGS S
  WHERE S.POSITION > 0
   AND S.fs_perm_sec_id = HE.fs_perm_sec_id
 GROUP BY FS_PERM_SEC_ID) AS stake_holdings,

(SELECT SUM(CURRENT_HOLDINGS)
 FROM
   (SELECT CURRENT_HOLDINGS
    FROM OWN_INST_HOLDINGS IHT
    WHERE FS_PERM_SEC_ID=HE.FS_PERM_SEC_ID
    ORDER BY CURRENT_HOLDINGS DESC LIMIT 10)A) AS top_10_inst_hodings,

 (SELECT SUM(OIH.current_holdings)
  FROM own_inst_holdings OIH
  WHERE OIH.fs_perm_sec_id = HE.fs_perm_sec_id) AS inst_holdings

FROM own_prices OP
JOIN h_security_ticker_exchange HE ON OP.fs_perm_sec_id = HE.fs_perm_sec_id
JOIN h_entity_sector HES ON HES.factset_entity_id = HE.factset_entity_id
WHERE HE.ticker_exchange = 'PG-NYS'
ORDER BY OP.price_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Ran an EXPLAIN ANALYSE and received the following results:

```
  QUERY PLAN
  Limit  (cost=223.39..223.39 rows=1 width=100) (actual time=2420.644..2420.645 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=223.39..223.39 rows=1 width=100) (actual time=2420.643..2420.643 rows=1 loops=1)
    Sort Key: op.price_date
    Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.26..223.39 rows=1 width=100) (actual time=2316.169..2420.566 rows=36 loops=1)
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.17..8.87 rows=1 width=104) (actual time=3.958..5.084 rows=36 loops=1)
                ->  Index Scan using h_sec_exch_factset_entity_id_idx on h_security_ticker_exchange he  (cost=0.09..4.09 rows=1 width=92) (actual time=1.452..1.454 rows=1 loops=1)
                      Index Cond: ((ticker_exchange)::text = 'PG-NYS'::text)
                ->  Index Scan using alex_prices on own_prices op  (cost=0.09..4.68 rows=33 width=23) (actual time=2.496..3.592 rows=36 loops=1)
                      Index Cond: ((fs_perm_sec_id)::text = (he.fs_perm_sec_id)::text)
          ->  Index Scan using alex_factset_entity_idx on h_entity_sector hes  (cost=0.09..4.09 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=0.076..0.077 rows=1 loops=36)
                Index Cond: (factset_entity_id = he.factset_entity_id)
          SubPlan 1
            ->  Index Only Scan using alex_factset_industry_code_idx on factset_industry_map fim  (cost=0.03..2.03 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=36)
                  Index Cond: (factset_industry_code = hes.industry_code)
                  Heap Fetches: 0
          SubPlan 2
            ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.08..2.18 rows=2 width=17) (actual time=0.735..0.735 rows=1 loops=36)
                  Group Key: s.fs_perm_sec_id
                  ->  Index Only Scan using own_stakes_holdings_perm_position_idx on own_stakes_holdings s  (cost=0.08..2.15 rows=14 width=17) (actual time=0.080..0.713 rows=39 loops=36)
                        Index Cond: ((fs_perm_sec_id = (he.fs_perm_sec_id)::text) AND (\position\ > 0::numeric))
                        Heap Fetches: 1155
          SubPlan 3
            ->  Aggregate  (cost=11.25..11.26 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.166..0.166 rows=1 loops=36)
                  ->  Limit  (cost=0.09..11.22 rows=10 width=6) (actual time=0.081..0.150 rows=10 loops=36)
                        ->  Index Only Scan Backward using alex_current_holdings_idx on own_inst_holdings iht  (cost=0.09..194.87 rows=175 width=6) (actual time=0.080..0.147 rows=10 loops=36)
                              Index Cond: (fs_perm_sec_id = (he.fs_perm_sec_id)::text)
                              Heap Fetches: 288
          SubPlan 4
            ->  Aggregate  (cost=194.96..194.96 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=66.102..66.102 rows=1 loops=36)
                  ->  Index Only Scan using alex_current_holdings_idx on own_inst_holdings oih  (cost=0.09..194.87 rows=175 width=6) (actual time=0.060..65.209 rows=2505 loops=36)
                        Index Cond: (fs_perm_sec_id = (he.fs_perm_sec_id)::text)
                 Heap Fetches: 33453
 Planning time: 1.581 ms
 Execution time: 2420.830 ms
```

Once we disable the SELECT SUM() for the 3 aggregates it speeds up considerably but it defeats the point of having a relational DB.

We are running the queries with NodeJS using PG plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) to connect and run the queries on the DB

How can we speed up the queries? What additional steps we could take? We have already indexed the DB and all the fields seems to be indexed properly but still it not fast enough.

Any help, comments and /or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You are using EC2 instead of RDS? What instance size are you using? Are you using EBS? What EBS volume type are you using? What is the size of the EBS volume(s)? What appears to be the bottleneck in your server monitoring, disk IO, CPU, network transfer?

Comment: I am using heroku addon which seems to host the DB on AWS

Comment: If you don't even know if it is hosted on an EC2 instance, perhaps you should tag the question with "Heroku" instead of any AWS tags. The PostgreSQL offering from Heroku is specific to Heroku and while it might use AWS resources behind the scenes, tags like `amazon-ec2` are not relevant to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but that does not answer the question.

Comment: Notice I posted a commented on your question. I didn't post an answer. My comment was meant to help you update your question to provide the necessary details so that someone might be able to provide an answer.

Comment: So ... are you using heroku postgres? Or something else? It's not clear from this. It sounds like you could be seeing either hint-bit writing activity or normal cold cache activity.

Comment: we are using heroku postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Nested loops with aggregates are generally a bad thing. The below should avoid that. (Untested; a SQLFiddle would have been helpful.) Give this a spin and let me know. I'm curious how the engine plays with the window function filter.

```
WITH    security
AS  (
    SELECT  HE.fs_perm_sec_id
,       HE.TICKER_EXCHANGE
,       HE.proper_name
,       OP.shares_outstanding
,       OP.price_date
FROM    own_prices                  AS OP
 JOIN   h_security_ticker_exchange  AS HE
  ON    OP.fs_perm_sec_id       = HE.fs_perm_sec_id
 JOIN   h_entity_sector             AS HES
  ON    HES.factset_entity_id   = HE.factset_entity_id
WHERE HE.ticker_exchange = 'PG-NYS'
)
SELECT  SE.fs_perm_sec_id
,       SE.TICKER_EXCHANGE
,       SE.proper_name
,       SE.shares_outstanding
,       S.stake_holdings
,       IHT.top_10_inst_holdings
,       OIH.inst_holdings
FROM    security    SE
 JOIN   (
        SELECT  S.fs_perm_sec_id
        ,       SUM(S.POSITION)     AS stake_holdings
        FROM    OWN_STAKES_HOLDINGS AS S
        WHERE   S.fs_perm_sec_id    IN (
                    SELECT  fs_perm_sec_id
                    FROM    security
                )
         AND    S.POSITION          > 0
        GROUP BY    S.fs_perm_sec_id
        )   AS S
  ON    SE.fs_perm_sec_id   = S.fs_perm_sec_id
 JOIN   (
        SELECT  IHT.FS_PERM_SEC_ID
        ,       SUM(IHT.CURRENT_HOLDINGS)   AS top_10_inst_holdings
        FROM    OWN_INST_HOLDINGS   AS IHT
        WHERE   IHT.FS_PERM_SEC_ID  IN (
                    SELECT  fs_perm_sec_id
                    FROM    security
                )
         AND    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY IHT.FS_PERM_SEC_ID
                    ORDER BY IHT.CURRENT_HOLDINGS DESC
                )                   <= 10
        GROUP BY    IHT.FS_PERM_SEC_ID
        )   AS IHT
  ON    SE.fs_perm_sec_id   = IHT.fs_perm_sec_id
 JOIN   (
        SELECT  S.fs_perm_sec_id
        ,       SUM(OIH.current_holdings)   AS inst_holdings
        FROM    own_inst_holdings   AS OIH
        WHERE   OIH.fs_perm_sec_id  IN (
                    SELECT  fs_perm_sec_id
                    FROM    security
                )
        GROUP BY    OIH.fs_perm_sec_id
        )   AS OIH
  ON    SE.fs_perm_sec_id   = OIH.fs_perm_sec_id
ORDER BY    SE.price_date
LIMIT   1
```